# JSON Escape Sequence

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

Im having trouble with my JSON because it show extra character which is not needed.**"\"**[image]

---

this is the code i've use to query it from my dbase.

```
public function getPostList(){
    $query = "CALL sample3()";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $post = new Post();
        $post->setId($row['id']); 
        $post->setBody($row['body']); 
      //$post->setImage($row['imgurl']);
       $post->setImage("sgwebpost.atwebpages.com/". $row['imgurl']);
        $post->setStamp($row['stamp']);
        $postList[]  = $post;
    }

    return array('post'=> $postList);
}

echo json_encode($handler->getPostList());
```

---

How can i remove that extra string? Big Help Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [valid JSON](http://json.org), and  is useful when there are `</script>` tags in your response, etc. But, if you want to remove it, you could use the [`JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) constant:

```
echo json_encode($handler->getPostList(), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Accepted :) I will ask another question again i hope you can help me again.

Comment: @Toshi: Glad to have been of help!